# How to install pre-installed Ubuntu 12.04 in beagleboard-xm board?

Tags: arm

I purchased new beagleboard-xm. Can you please tell me, how to install Ubuntu 12.04 in SDcard, and load it in beagleboard-Xm?

I downloaded the img.gz file from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OMAP

Comment: This might help http://hereirestinremorse.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/ubuntu-make-an-iso-of-your-mmc/

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience using a BeagleBoard, the preinstalled images from Canonical do not install well.  Following the instructions here to create a running installation via netinstall may be more advantageous: http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Method_2:_Use_the_NetInstall_method.  I have done those three or four times and currently have my BeagleBoard-xM running Xubuntu 12.04.